# DataAnnotations Validation only implemented in MVC?

Tags: wpf, winforms, .net-4.0, data-annotations

I somehow missed the introduction of DataAnnotations.  I’ve been looking at them off and on for the last couple of weeks.  It seems like everything I’m finding ties back to MVC.  Are there any full implementations for doing validation with WPF, WinForms, etc.?

If so, any pointers/links would be appreciated.
If not, are there plans to introduce integrated support in the future?

My current interests lie in WPF so that's really what I'm looking for.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karl Shifflett from the Microsoft patterns and practices team has a detailed [video on how to use the Data Annotations attributes in WPF](http://www.vimeo.com/11585675). His source code is available via a link at the bottom of his [blog post on his Stuff demo application](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2010/05/09/stuff-wpf-line-of-business-using-mvvm-video-tutorial/).

Data Annotations is a nice middle ground between that and the ad-hoc validation one would normally see in the WPF books and tutorials and the more powerful Enterprise Validation Application Block that @Evan Larsen mentioned above. Plus, as you noticed, using Data Annotations allows for sharing of models with ASP.NET applications.

Comment: My interest at this point is largely academic/self-gratifying and this totaly nails what I was looking for.  That being said, I still have a LOT of reading to do on Enterprise Library validation (thanks @Even Larsen) and I suspect that is what I will go with on my production stuff.  I may modify some of my approach based on Karl's work though.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding WPF, DataAnnotations support is not built in, but it shouldn't be too difficult to hook in to your own app.

The demo app of my open source library [PDX](http://code.google.com/p/pdx/) shows one way to do it, but the documentation for 0.2 isn't quite finished yet :)

Here's another way to do it: http://babaandthepigman.wordpress.com/2010/02/14/wpf-commanding-and-data-annotations-validation/